# auto tag video and add to itunes on windows

Tags: windows-7, video, itunes, mp4, tags

I'm looking for an app similar to Auto TV Tagger that monitors a folder and auto magically tags the file either through a webservice or by the file name given then adds it to itunes in the proper section ie Movies for movies TV shows for tv etc i was going write an extension for Auto TV tagger but there is no source available and im not sure how to tear apart the exe for the dlls that do the tagging. 
Anyone have any ideas on apps plugins or an api that do this ?

Answer (score 0):

[MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) can be used to set some tags on a file, as follows:

```
MP4Box -itags writer=me file.mp4
```

You can have a list of supported tags with MP4Box -tag-list. If some fields are not supported, [file an issue](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues).